# What is the difference between unescapeJava and unescapeJson from StringEscapeUtils

Tags: java, stringescapeutils

As per the [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html) documentation, looks like both these methods [`unescapeJson`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJson(java.lang.String)) and [`unescapeJava`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String)) does the similar thing.

I tried using both methods it works fine as below:

**Example:**

```
String input = "{\"key\":\"ab\u2019cd\"}"
System.out.println(unescapeJava(input)); // outputs: {"key":"ab’cd"}
System.out.println(unescapeJson(input)); // outputs: {"key":"ab’cd"}
```

Both of these statements print exactly same output. So, what is the difference and when to use which method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same, as you can see in [the sources](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html):

```
public static final CharSequenceTranslator UNESCAPE_JSON = UNESCAPE_JAVA;
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I got it now, but will accept the answer after 3 minutes as SO does not allow to accept till it completes 3 minutes : D